# Get value form url php through anothe page

Tags: php, html, post

i am post the value to the net page via url like this.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="index.php?page=edit_fuel_record.php &trans_id = <?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white"></i>
            Edit
        </a></span>
```

on the other page i am trying to retrieve the value. yes i can see it on the url, but i can't retrieve it in code. here is how i am trying to retrieve it
echo "The ID is"."".$_GET[trans_id];
Its giving me null

if i post values this way

```
<p align="center"><a href="ReportBySite_csv.php?date1=<?php echo $_POST['date1'];?>&date2=<?php echo $_POST['date2'];?>&siteid=<?php echo $_POST['siteid'];?>">Download CSV</a></p>
```

its working fine.

the difference is if i go through the index page i can't use the value posted.

Comment: ` &trans_id = ` I doubt the spaces in the URL are helping.

Comment: Remove the spaces from the first url

Comment: thanx guys, it was the spaces

Answer (score 0):

if you use the query string you should use 
    $_GET['value'] with the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Remove space from the url. there is extra space after 'trans_id'

Answer (score 0):

You echo'd wrong. if you don't use quotes I think PHP will interpet it as a constant? Try the code below:

```
echo "The ID is" . $_GET['trans_id'];
```

Also change first piece of code with this:

```
a class="btn btn-info" href="index.php?page=edit_fuel_record.php&trans_id=<?=$row['id']; ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white"></i>Edit</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing the values through the URL. that means it is a get method of data passing.

To access this in another page you should use **$_GET** intead of **$_POST** like

```
if(isset($_GET)){
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!=""){
        $page=$_GET['page'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['trans_id ']) && !empty($_GET['trans_id ']) && $_GET['trans_id ']!=""){
        $trans_id =$_GET['trans_id '];
    }

    echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href="index.php?page=edit_fuel_record.php&trans_id='.$row['id']; .'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white"></i>Edit</a></span>';

}
```

please try this way.